# How to create advance architecture for ASP.NET MVC 5 and WebAPI 2 technology with Angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm beginner of  ASP.NET MVC 5 and WebAPI 2 technology and Angular js .
I wanted to develop project for demo purpose. This project will be used with following layer

1. A project "Web.Front" - ASP.NET MVC 5
2. A project "WebApi2"
3. A project "Models" - Class library - using  Code First
4. Repository Class library

i did goggling but unable to find good sample project.please anybody having good artical or sample project ,share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a "Project Template" nor an example project at hand atm. But first of all, when you say ASP.NET MVC5 and WebAPi 2 your mostly referring to the same thing. Besides, there will be little reason to have any ASP.NET views other than your index.html...

Angular will already handle all your templating needs. So for most parts, stick with API controllers.

**Strike 3. and 4.**

Don't use a Models class library, repository api, code first ect... That will just leave you to define you model in two places, if your doing this to learn, go with a JSON driven model and use a NO-SQL database, then let your Angular app define the data and the model... For .NET Raven DB might give you an easy start...

---

From that point on, it should be fairly easy for you to create a new web project in Visual Studio, trim it down to the absolute minimal code (leaving just the Index file and a Home controller)... Then build on top of that...

Node and Bower are great for package management to pull down things like Angular (https://angularjs.org/), Angular-routing (http://dotjem.github.io/angular-routing/), JQuery (http://jquery.com/), Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) etc...